# Phonegap: FileUploadOptions() is not working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm working on angularJS v1.2 and building its APK via build.phonegap.com. In my config file it is giving error while adding `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" />` file transfer plugin. This is why i can't use use `FileUploadOptions()` to upload files. I have tried

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", results[i]);

var objXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
objXhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
objXhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
objXhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
    console.log( objXhr.responseText );
    alert('file upload response: '+JSON.stringify( objXhr.responseText  ));
    }
};
objXhr.open("POST", "https://somedomain.com/upload_images.php");
objXhr.send(fd);
```

`results[i]` is image URL that fetched via `$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)`.

On my php file im not getting anything via `$_FILES[]`. Phonegap told [here](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html) and [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) that `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` is no longer available for phonegap. I'm not sure how to implement `XMLHttpRequest` this in my current scenario to set properties of `results[i]` so that it can be distinguish as file on php file to get files via `$_FILES`.